# What does it means to had requirement on "Ability to see beyond immediate assignment to achieve results."

Tags: meaning, expressions

I see one job requirement posting on a mechanical engineering job searching website that it said "Ability to see beyond immediate assignment to achieve results." What is is meaning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The author likely wants you to have a holistic or encompassing perspective on your duties.

They want someone who considers the larger goals, purpose, and implications of each individual task or chunk of work, so that the longer-term goals are accomplished more effectively or efficiently.

There is a related idiom:

> Don't miss the forest for the trees.

Answer (score 0):

I want to mention one issue in your question. The "What does it means?" is wrong. The word "mean" should remain in the infinitive as it is used with an auxiliary verb in the question. So it should be "What does it mean?" not "What does it means?"